# Call C# function of aspx page which is loaded in another aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have loaded a sub.aspx page in `DIV(id=inner)` of the main.aspx page using jquery code.

```
$('#inner').load('sub.aspx');
```

Now my sub.aspx page contains Dropdownlist

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="subclass2" 
         runat="server" 
         AutoPostBack="True" 
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="subclass2_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

The `subclass2_SelectedIndexChanged` function is in sub.aspx.cs which is not getting called.

How can I make this function work?

```
IF I LOAD THE sub.aspx INDIVIDUALLY, IT WORKS FINE.
i.e. dropdrown is successfully getting filled using database.
```

**Solved: Master Page is the Solution for this. Rather then opening the aspx page within aspx page, Use ContentPlaceHolder Tag of Master page which renders the respective pages automatically.**

But if anyone gets solution without **Master Page**, plz share its solution.

Comment: DOes the DDL get filled?  If so, where is that code?  I think the call to the server is not getting registered because the page was loaded with JS.  Perhaps you could create a JS function for an AJAX call?

Comment: This is not going to work under normal circumstances. ASP.NET presumes there is only one `form` element around the whole page , and goes unpredictably wild when there are several. So you should reconsider you approach to something not using inner page.